# node2vec initial embedding

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, word2vec, graphs

I am referring to the following implementation of node2vec: https://github.com/eliorc/node2vec

Is there a way to have a "smart initialization" with node2vec, i.e., to start the algorithm with an embedding that is not random but precomputed in a certain way? For instance, when I use the spring_layout from NetworkX, I pass the initialization via `pos = my_initialization`, and the computations are a lot faster. Obviously, there is no such argument with node2vec, but I was wondering if there is some workaround via underlying word2vec.

Comment: cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64334494/10495893